# Replace filename with containing folder name (csh)

Tags: files, scripting, rename, tcsh, csh

I have the exact same question as this [poster](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78938/replace-filename-with-parent-folder-name) but, I'm using csh.

I can get the filename I want

```
set x = V_181_V_d_2_um_phi_4.50_eV_tOn_0.5_ns/SteadyState_out.e
cat "`echo $x | cut -d "/" -f1`.e"
    cat: V_181_V_d_2_um_phi_4.50_eV_tOn_0.5_ns.e: No such file or directory
```

But I cannot figure out how to do anything with that string. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first piece of advice would be to change your shell to something else. That said, this should do what you want:

```
set file = "V_181_V_d_2_um_phi_4.50_eV_tOn_0.5_ns/SteadyState_out.e"
set newname = "`echo $file | cut -d "/" -f1`.e"
mv "$file" "$newname"
```

That will not save the file in its original directory. I don't know if that's what you want since you didn't actually explain what you are trying to achieve, but if you want the file to stay in its original directory, you can do:

```
set dirname = "V_181_V_d_2_um_phi_4.50_eV_tOn_0.5_ns"
set file = "SteadyState_out.e"
set newname = "`echo $dirname | cut -d "/" -f1`.e"
mv "$dirname"/"$file" "$dirname"/"$newname"
```

Answer (score 1):

`csh` (and `tcsh` and `zsh`) have `:h`, `:t` modifiers to extract head (dirname) or tail (basename) of a file.

So you can do:

```
 set x = V_181_V_d_2_um_phi_4.50_eV_tOn_0.5_ns/SteadyState_out.e
 mv -- $x:q $x:h/$x:h:t:q
```